# I got an error while using cy.origin() and trying to execute any command on the new context

Tags: javascript, html, automation, cypress

I've been trying to use cy.origin() to access a new origin in the same test, and I'm being able to! However once inside I'm getting this error. Also I do have the Cypress.on('uncaught:exception') under support > commands.js

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

Any clue?

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
    cy.visit('/');
});

  it.only("User is able to create a proposal", () => {
    sis.openAccount();
    sis.createProposal();
    cy.wait(35000);
    cy.origin(ENVS_URL, () => {
      cy.visit(ENVS_PATH);
      cy.url().should("contain", ENVS_PATH);
      cy.get('iframes-container').find('#propprefs > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > div > span.left')  
//It fails here, even if I do a simple cy.wait().
    });
  });
```

[image: error]

*Ignore how the get is written, it is just a random example for the post*.

Answer (score 0):

since cypress `v10.1.0`
you can just set `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true` inside the `cypress.config.js` file.

Comment: It seems you can set `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` since v9.6.0: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-6-1

Comment: More details on this option here: https://cypress.io/blog/2022/04/25/cypress-9-6-0-easily-test-multi-domain-workflows-with-cy-origin/

Comment: I think the answer should be improved by added links to docs and by explaining the option!

Comment: `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` does not exist anymore since v12. Since then it is enabled by default: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#12-0-0